Light Refraction Material
How do I make this glass/metal refraction with the light having those sharp and soft edges within the object?

If you want a black background like the one you show, you could plug a Layer Weight (Facing output) into a ColorRamp with your color spectrum, into the Base Color of a Principled BSDF that has the Metallic at 1, you could even plug the ColorRamp into the Emission that you set at 1:


Thank you! I want to know if there's a more deliberate way though like in the other picture I just added?
